# How do I return multiple object types (String,int,int) in Java, when I am calling a different package?

Tags: java

I am trying to pass multiple object types (String, int, int) into another package1, and get that package1 to return back (String, int, int). But I want to do this without importing the original package2 into package1 by passing a class.

Method1: Pass an Object List, and cast it back to String/int at caller. (I've read passing objects is a taboo and should either pass classes or one specific type only)

```
//package1 - cannot import any other packages
public List<Object> returnvalue (String aString, int aInt, int bInt) {
  //Just an example of processed values
  aString = aString + "append"; 
  aInt++;
  bInt = bInt+2;

  List<Object> returnvalue = new ArrayList<>();

  returnvalue.add(aString);
  returnvalue.add(aInt);
  returnvalue.add(bInt);

  return returnvalue;
}

//package2 - can import package1 inside
int aInt = 1;
int bInt = 1;
List<Object> receivevalue = package1.returnvalue("aString",aInt,bInt);
String receivestring = (String)receivevalue.get(0);
String receiveint1 = (int)receivevalue.get(1);
String receiveint2 = (int)receivevalue.get(2);
```

Method2: Pass a String List, and convert it inside the method. (This way I don't pass objects)

```
//package1 - cannot import any other packages
public List<String> returnvalue (String aString, String aInt, String bInt) {
  //Just an example of processed values
  aString = aString + "append";

  int tmpInt = Integer.valueOf(aInt);
  tmpInt++;
  aInt = String.valueOf(tmpInt);

  int tmpInt2 = Integer.valueOf(bInt);
  tmpInt2=tmpInt2-2;
  bInt = String.valueOf(tmpInt2);

  List<String> returnvalue = new ArrayList<>();

  returnvalue.add(aString);
  returnvalue.add(aInt);
  returnvalue.add(bInt);

  return returnvalue;
}

//package2 - can import package1 inside
int aInt = 1;
int bInt = 1;
List<String> receivevalue = package1.returnvalue("aString",aInt,bInt);
String receivestring = receivevalue.get(0);
String receiveint1 = receivevalue.get(1);
String receiveint2 = receivevalue.get(2);
```

From what Ive read, most seems to suggest to create a class and pass that class, so that it has type safety and it would be much more readable. However without calling package2 into package1, i believe this is not possible? And I want to do this without importing any model class whatsoever, package1 must be completely independant.

I am wondering which is the best, and if there is any better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: In java lingo, do you know what `package` means?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `String receiveint1 = (int)receivevalue.get(1);` ?

Comment: I want to use that string to print out some values.

And package as in it is in a completely different package, IE package1 = com.package1.receivevalue, package2 = com.package2.passvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in package1 create a POJO class to hold your input/output values
e.g:

```
class Data {
    public String s;
    public int a1;
    public int a1;
}
```

then you can change the signature of:

```
public List<Object> returnvalue (String aString, int aInt, int bInt)
```

to

```
public Data returnValue(Data aData)
```

**UPDATE**

assuming you have 2 classes in package1

*Data.java:*

```
package package1;

public class Data {
    public String s;
    public int a1;
    public int a2;
}
```

and *Solution.java:*

```
package package1;

public class Solution {
    public Data returnValue(Data input) {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.s = input.s + "append";
        data.a1 = input.a1 + 1;
        data.a2 = input.a2 + 2;

        return data;
    }
}
```

you can use them in packate2 as follows *App.java*:

```
package package2;

import package1.Data;
import package1.Solution;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Data input = new Data();

        input.s = "ipsum";
        input.a1 = 1;
        input.a2 = 2;

        Solution solution = new Solution();
        Data result = solution.returnValue(input);

        // use result
    }
}
```

Comment: If I created the POJO class in package1, how would package2 know what the Data class is?

Comment: you have to import package1 in package2 to use the returnValue method, so you'll also know the Data class

Comment: Thanks, this solution works great and meets the expectations. package1 doesnt import package2 and package2 is able to use the POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a java class, which has all three (String, int, int) attributes in it and then you can return object of it. Hope it helps.

Comment: how does package2 receive back the values? Would you mind writing an example based on my example in the original question?